# How to resolve this formula in Matlab ( sum of combinations)

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

How to resolve this simple formula in Matlab?

[image]

This is sum of combinations. There is function `nchoosek` to get number of combinations (n,k).

`nchoosek(k+m, i)` will find this for an `i`. But how to find for all ranges of `i`?

So, the only way to resolve this, is to write loop? Or I can do it inline - with matlab functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sum goes from `0` to `m+k`, then the answer is `2^(m+k)`, no iteration required. If the sum is from `1` to `m+k`, then the answer is `2^(m+k)-1`.

If you're insistent, then the `for` loop looks like this:

```
s = 0;
for i=1:qu
  s = s + nchoosek(m+k,i);
end
```

The function [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html) can take a vector as the first argument, but not as the second.

Comment: but only if `qu = m+k` ;) for other cases I will write a loop. I thaught, there is a way to use `nchoosek` with the second argument-vector